# Getting Exception While Subscribing TextBox LosingFocus Event UWP XAMl

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am Dynamically creating a `TextBox Control` and I have Subscribed the `TextBox LosingFocus Event` and Its working fine on Local Machine but it is giving exception on Virtual Machine.

Getting the Following Error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox' to
>   type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.IUIElement5

and The Stacktrace is:

```
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD,
IntPtr& ppTarget) at
Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.add_LosingFocus(TypedEventHandler`2 value) at
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.NativeOrStaticEventRegistrationImpl.AddEventHandler[T](Func`2
addMethod, Action`1 removeMethod, T handler)
at
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler[T](Func`2
addMethod, Action`1 removeMethod, T handler)
_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
```

Please Help me To Solve That Issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of UWP is your app targeting and which version of Windows 10 is on the virtual machine? The problem is very likely that the VM is running an earlier version of Windows 10 which didn't have the `LosingFocus` event yet, so you will either have to use `LostFocus`, conditional code, or implement the functionality in a different way

Comment: WIndows 10 Version of  VM is 1607(OS Build 14393.447)     and My UWP  App Minimum Version is Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)

Comment: When I am Using the LostFocus Event then in Some Scenario the FostFocus Event is not firing.(When we click on a Listview Then the LostFocus event is not firing)

Comment: Easy way to check if the API is actually present on Anniversary update is to set Target version SDK for the app to 14393 (not min version, target). If VS shows an error, then it means `LosingFocus` was not there yet in 14393

Comment: I have Changed My Target version of App to 14393 but still getting the same error.

Comment: And can the app be compiled? Could you try installing UWP Platform Specific Analyzer If it tells you some recommendation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/platform-specific/platformspecificanalyzer

Comment: My VM is windows server 2016 1607(OS Build 14393.447)

Answer (score 0):

The `LosingEvent` has been introduced in the Windows API contract V4 (Windows build 15063+).

It is not available on the Windows build you are using in your VM (14393).

You can see the minimal OS/API contract version in the [LosingEvent documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.losingfocusevent#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_LosingFocusEvent)

> Additional features and requirements
>
> Device family : Windows 10 Creators Update (introduced v10.0.15063.0)
>   **API contract  : Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced v4)**

Since you're minimal target is Windows build 10240 (API contract V1), you need to perform a runtime check before registering to this event.

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract"), 4, 0)
{
    // This device supports all APIs in UniversalApiContract version 4.0
}
```

This is the only way to validate if the API is available. You will have a detailed explanation about how to target multiple Windows version [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/#zaiJAOOa1K8rlP1C.97)

If the event is absolutly mandatory for what you want to do, you will need to upgrade the minimum target platform to 15063. By doing this, your application will no longer be able to run on older OS builds.